Leading a choir where singers are at different skill levels
I've gotten into a situation where I'm leading an acapella group/choir with members of varying skill levels. Some of the members are decent/good singers, and some of the newer members are at an absolute beginner level. This naturally leads to issues during practice sessions together, as the more experienced members breeze through a section whereas some of the newer members struggle to hit each individual note even kind of correctly. While I do believe that the novice singers have potential for improvement, I've felt that there is a need to rethink how the sessions are structured so that members actually feel like they're getting their time's worth from participating.
Has anyone here been in a similar situation, and how did you handle it? How well did your approach work? What I'm looking for here is some advice on whether one should think about splitting the group up in some sense (and let members of different skill levels practice separately), and whether there is any value in having members of very different skill levels singing together.

One clarifying question;
Is the skill differential a matter of the more experienced singers reading the sheet music more quickly and instictively?
Or are we talking about the inexperienced singers simply singing flat or sharp, or being distracted from their individual parts by the sound of all those other voices?

@Sparquelito The lowest skill level is basically not being able to hit the correct note (even remotely close) while hearing it being played, and needing maybe 10-15 seconds of direct instruction on how to change their pitch to reach the correct note, while the highest skill level is being able to sing simple passages A vista, given a starting note.

I got it.
Yes, I would consider splitting them into two skill groups, as you implied, and working toward a combined session in coming weeks!

The beginners will have the easiest time if they are standing next to a more experienced singer who is singing the same part they are. Also singing the melody is easiest, followed by bass line, and then inner voices are hard.

Yeah, this is another big problem. Most of the singers with the least experience have a vocal range which falls into one of the hardest parts, and there is not a single competent singer within that part right now besides myself - but I'm conducting, so ideally I wouldn't have to sing at all!

If you have the time, I suspect individual, private coaching of the novices instead of trying to coach them as a separate group is warranted. That way, the experienced singers feel less discriminated against.

Could use more info here.  Knowing the age level of the singers (kids/teens/adults) would help a ton.  I'd approach it differently for different groups

@nuggethead This is an adult amateur group.

What kind of choir is it? How did you end up with such varying levels? What is the motivation for the experienced people to be in this group?

@MichaelCurtis While it's somewhat irrelevant, I can say this much. Firstly, we have a lot of fun and do all kinds of things together. The choir is a part of it, and is what brought us all together in the first place. Secondly, the effects of the covid pandemic and other societal factors have made it very difficult for us to recruit new members. We're not the only ones suffering in this regard, but it does make it difficult to argue for not letting people join who are interested.

It's important to respect your singers' time. You don't want the inexperienced singers to feel stuck, or for the experienced ones to feel like they're wasting their time. The following ideas helped me train a 50-voice ad hoc amateur choir to sing two anthems and the service music for a bishop's ordination over three weeks (3-4 1-hour rehearsals:)

Practice tracks: email everyone recordings of their own parts, preferably isolated (with the other parts going on quietly simultaneously,) as well as texts and translations. This was what I got the most positive feedback on.
Sectionals: For example, if it's a 4-part choir, have Sopranos and Altos show up for half of one rehearsal, and Tenors and Basses show up for the other half, and drill parts that way. Even better, have someone help: half the voice parts go to a different location with your helper for an entire rehearsal, who doesn't have to be very experienced, to drill the parts.
Learn pieces backwards: Start with the final section, then rehearse the last two sections, then final three, and so forth, for each chunk of music. This is extremely efficient for solo instrument practice, and I've found it carries over well into ensemble work.
Ear training: in the long term, instead of doing those tacky vocal drills that don't achieve much, do simple ear training and music literacy exercises with the choir. 10 minutes per week is enough to move the needle with this.
Singer positioning: Place your most accurate singers in the most ideal situation to help others. This doesn't mean you put them right next to the weakest singers, necessarily. But make sure they're audible by the people within their section who learn more by ear.

A good book to read would be "Chorus Confidential" by William Dehning. This really helped me with my mindset as a choral conductor.

Sectionals are the right answer here. These other things can help, but if you have good musicians, they also know a bit about how to become good musicians, and if you sell it right, they will feel acknowledged for their contributions while the newer musicians get more individual attention by virtue of having more people teaching them. If the section leaders want the remaining things here, great, but empower your people and they'll achieve (egad, teenage me would hate me right now).

All above options are extremely valid, but I agree that sectionals are most important: as Tim's answers properly explains, hearing different lines is confusing to the inexperienced: "divide and conquer" tactics works well in music too, at any level. Further subdivisions could even be considered if each section is too large: if a section has 8-10 or more (75% of which inexperienced), split that group even more, ensuring that each sub-group has at least one skilled singer: instruct those singers as being "lead", put them in the middle, and tell the others to carefully listen to them.

Some passages may be easier than others, but that difference must not be dismissed. On the contrary: "easier" passages may help fine tuning the ensemble, enforcing existing capabilities, while difficult ones may require further splitting that will help both the practising people and those who are not singing at that moment. Note that this is of utmost importance at any level: whenever you pay attention to a small section (or an individual), ensure that everybody else is paying attention as well, as even "passive learning" is useful, especially at beginner's levels.

@Richard "simple ear training and music literacy exercises" do you use a particular resource, or types of exercises?

I'm glad people here agree with the sectional approach. I think it maximizes rehearsal time with amateur choirs or even semi-pro. The accompanist's help is key, and using a sound-before-sight-based approach to learn each line.

@MichaelCurtis I go very light on warmups. In my opinion they usually don't accomplish much and the time is better used on the music. I'll probably be disagreed with on this point. You can even find books full of them by people with Ph.Ds - waste of ink and money. I base "warmups" on the rep  I.E. if it's full of triads, we warm up with triads. However, such exercises are always for ear training purposes for the longer-term benefit of the choir. I'm sure there are more complete answers on this site about ear training in general.

With inexperienced singers, hearing different lines being sung around them is at least disconcerting, at most, off putting, and yes, they will not be able to pitch their own parts at all. After years of doing this, personally, I need the other parts to pitch mine against theirs, but that's obviously not the case here!
What's needed is to practise each section as a section together, but without the  distraction of other voices singing discrete parts. Use of a piano will help a lot - you probably do that anyway, or you should. Even though it's an acapella choir, they need absolute pitches at the stage they're at.
At some point, you can play both their part and the melody line while they sing, so they can still pitch off the piano, while listening to how the two lines fit each other.
Having recordings of each part separately will be a great help, also, which you'll probably have to make yourself, or get them done.
There will, of course, be those budding singers who will never reach the level needed - perhaps they felt being in an ensemble would mask their shortcomings, perhaps their enthusiasm was greater than their ability. If you've inherited such a group, it's an impossible situation to find yourself in, I'm afraid.
Exercises such as singing scales and arpeggios should always be part of the warm up process, and if the pitches waver mid-song, then go back to singing them, as well as certain harder-to-sing intervals from the song.
When re-assembling, put satb in four parts of the room, so they all sing in a homogenous group, with the weakest group nearest the piano, which should be used frequently. For me, no piano, no choir!

Thanks for the advice, I'll keep it in mind when talking with other members how we should proceed. At this moment we do have midi recordings of every part in every song in our repertoire, but when you mention recordings is it better to have actual recordings of someone singing it correctly?

Absolutely - either with pno, or acapella, or both
